# Выборка mime типов

Tags: node.js, типы, javascript

Есть over1000 mime типов.
Собственно вопрос: как организовать поиск этих типов? Как сделать так, чтобы затрачивалось минимальное количество ресурсов?
Сейчас все данные находятся в файлике вида:

```
video/x-f4v     f4v
video/x-fli     fli
video/x-flv     flv
video/x-m4v     m4v
```

Собственно парсить файл каждый раз вообще не вариант. Как решение я придумал всё это дело запихнуть в key=value сторадж, либо весь список перевести в json формат и загружать его при старте приложения.

Собственно вопрос: как лучше сделать?

юзаю node.js

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый - да, напрямую в код. 
Самый, имхо, правильный - в базу данных, так как только сервер в состоянии адекватно проверить майм.

Comment: такой вопрос: что будет с памятью? что означает "только сервер в состоянии адекватно проверить майм". mime тип я проверяю по расширению файла.

Comment: С памятью - будет жраться. Не очень много. Даже при большой нагрузке.
mime тип я проверяю по расширению файла// Вот это один из неадекватных способов. Зачем вам майм, если вы смотрите расширение? По нему и ориентируйтесь дальше... Я могу создать текстовый файл, а расширение сменить на ваш flv. При этом mime у него чудесно останется text/plain в общем случае.

Comment: у меня файлосторадж на node.js. В хедеры при отдаче файлов нужно прописывать mime тип, чтобы у клиента файл нормально обработался для закачки. Я просто не пойму, вы предлагайте майм тип брать их свойств файла или как?

Comment: Именно так. А хранение только для проверки подходит ли вам этот тип.

Comment: Считаю что это не практично. Слишком много ресурсов будет затрачиваться. Проще смотреть расширение файла и полагаясь на расширение файла отдавать mime тип. А то, что вы смените расширение файла - это уже проблема конечных пользователей. Мне ничего не мешает также вместе с расширением и mime тип поменять. Вообще вариант такой: загружать в общую память главные типы, и по надобности из key=value хранилища тащить недостающие в память. Хоть и экономия на спичках, но зато в тысячных масштабах экономия на лицо.